# What are the versioning or revisioning packages for MongoMapper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongomapper

I'm looking for a few versioning packages for MongoMapper. I'm looking for something like the Mongoid::Versioning module.

Are there any other gems?

---

**Update**: the following is a list of what I've found or what users have suggested in their answers to this question.

- [mm-versionable](http://rubygems.org/gems/mm-versionable)
- [mongo_mapper_acts_as_versioned](https://github.com/gigamo/mongo_mapper_acts_as_versioned)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked [mongo_mapper_acts_as_versioned](https://github.com/gigamo/mongo_mapper_acts_as_versioned)? It's a port of technoweenie's acts_as_versioned but for MongoMapper.